# want get curent Adresse Location

Tags: java, android-studio, location, android-permissions, geocoder

I am developing an application that allows to retrieve the current location address using Geocoder.
this is the step to get location adresse that i follow :

1. check if GPS is enable on device
2. if it is request Location permissionspermissions else if GPS is disable on device request enable it than request permission
3. initialise Geocoder and get adresse latitude and logitude the get Adresse

if the GPS is Enable before clicking on button to get Location EveryThing work fine .
but the problem is when the GPS is disable whene clicking on button to get Location even if the app request to enable it and it will be enable i get this error message
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference**

code that i used

> Onclick Methode (test if GPS enabled than call getLocation Methode)

```
        locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Check permissions
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);

            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext())
                    .checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

            result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {

                    try {
                        LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "GPS is already tured on" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getCurrentLocation();
                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                try {
                                    ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                    resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(HomeActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                                   ex.printStackTrace();

                                }
                                break;

                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                                //Device does not have location
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

> GetLocation methode

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void getCurrentLocation() {

    int picd = 0;
    if (picd == 0) {
        if (!checkLocationFinePermission() || !checkLocationCoarsePermission() ) {
            requestLocationPermission();
        } else {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                    try {
                        //initialize geoCoder
                        Location location = task.getResult();
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(HomeActivity.this
                                , Locale.getDefault());

                        //initialize adresse
                        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                                location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1
                        );

                        //setAdresse
                        adresseEditText.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i("TAG", "onComplete: " + e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```